# How to create a superuser in Django with Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, django, shell, docker

Recently,I'm tring to deploy an application with docker.I get a problem about how to write a start script which will execute on Linux. An example is as fellow:

Usually,we create super user like this:

```
iMac:mysite yetongxue$ python manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'yetongxue'): root
Email address: example@qq.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
Superuser created successfully.
```

But when deploy application with docker,I must write this command in a script which will execute after the docker container start.How can I set the username ,email and password in the script? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than use the `createsuperuser` management command you can [provide a fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/).

You'll need to provide a fixture for the `auth.user` model. For the password you can generate one via the Django shell

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
>>> make_password('password')
```

Your final fixture should look like:

```
[
    { "model": "auth.user",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "<output of make_password()>"
            "is_superuser": true,
            "is_staff": true,
            "is_active": true
        }
    }
]
```